# Programmatically plot sub events of top events using ggplot: R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, geom-bar

I have a df like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

Events <- c("A_1","A_2","A_3","B_1","B_2","B_3","C_1","C_2","C_3","D_1","D_2","D_3","E_1","E_2","E_3")
Percentage_Occur <- c(4.6,6.5,1.3,3.4,6.6,5.5,7.8,2.2,2.4,2.1,6.6,5.9,4.9,11.1,4.3)
df1 <- data.frame(Events,Percentage_Occur)
```

I am trying to combines these sub events into individual category to determine the top 3 events and hence I do it like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(df1)
df2$Events <- gsub("*_.*", "\\1", df2$Events)
df2 <- df2 %>% group_by(Events) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum(., na.rm = T)))
df2 <- df2[ order(-df2[,2]), ]

ggplot(df2, aes(reorder(Events,Percentage_Occur), Percentage_Occur)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + coord_flip() +
  xlab("Events")
```

[image]

Once I am able to visualize the top 3 events (In this case they are E,B,D), I would like to plot the sub events of these top 3events in a separate plot like this.

[image]

I manually did this by extracting the sub events for the top events. Since this is a sample dataset, I was able to do it. I would like to apply the logic to a bigger dataset that I have.

All I want is to determine the top events (which I am able to do), and then somehow programatically plot the corresponding sub events for those top events without manually looking at the dataframe and extracting it. One of the reason is because these events change over time and would like to run this type of logic every 2 hours to see any new events that get to the top. Kindly please provide your inputs on this and help me in moving forward.

Note: I would also like to have better colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to automatically extract the top 3 events, you can process your data with:

```
library(data.table)
library(splitstackshape)

dt <- cSplit(df1, "Events", sep="_", drop=FALSE)[, tot := sum(Percentage_Occur), Events_1
                                                 ][order(-tot,Events_1,-Percentage_Occur)
                                                   ][, top := rleid(tot)
                                                     ][top <= 3]
```

And then with the help of `scale_fill_manual` and `reorder()`, you will get a plot with nicer colors & also ordered bars within the groups:

```
# create a vector for the labels of the events in the legend
# this is needed to get the legend in the right order
lbls <- dt$Events

# create the plot
ggplot(dt, aes(x=reorder(Events_1,-tot), y=Percentage_Occur, fill=reorder(Events,-Percentage_Occur), color="black")) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge(width=0.8), width=0.7) +
  geom_text(aes(y=1, label=Events), position = position_dodge(width=0.8), angle=90) +
  labs(title="Occurence by Event", x="Events", y="Percentage Occurance") +
  scale_color_manual(values = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual("Events", breaks = lbls,
                    values = c('#d53e4f','#3288bd','#fee08b','#ffffbf','#66c2a5','#f46d43','#fdae61','#abdda4','#e6f598')) +
  guides(color=FALSE) +
  theme_minimal()
```

which will result in:

[image]

You can adapt the color-values in `scale_fill_manual` to your own preferences.

---

The data preparation can also be done with `dplyr`/`tidyr` (although you will still need `data.table` for `rleid` function):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)

df1 <- df1 %>% separate(Events, c("Event","Subevent"), sep="_", remove=FALSE) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Event) %>%
  mutate(tot = sum(Percentage_Occur)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(-tot,-Percentage_Occur) %>%
  mutate(top = rleid(tot)) %>%      # for this part you need data.table
  filter(top <= 3)
```

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic and exactly what I wanted. I have one more small request regarding ordering the sub events in the plot (For example, I would like to see the bar plots ordered for sub events too. I mean, if we make it appear so that E_2,E_1,E_3 etc instead of the current). Please let me know if this is not clear.

Comment: Absolutely wonderful. Thank you so much Jaap. I used this logic in my large dataset and works like charm. I just wanted to know if we can modify the geom_text so that labels appear on top of the each bar vertically rather than inside the bars. This is because my event names seem to go outside the bars .

Comment: @Sharath That's certainly possible. Change `y = 1` to for example `y = Percentage_Occur` or `y = Percentage_Occur + 1` in the `aes` of `geom_text`. Furthermore, you can use `hjust` and `vjust` to customize the position of the labels. See`?geom_text` for more details.